# c++: definition of dllimport function not allowed, building with visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, macros

I'm using visual studio 2010 to build a .dll. I wrote up a trial as:

```
// trialDLL.h
#ifndef TRIALDLL_H_
#define TRIALDLL_H_

// ... MyMathFuncs class definition omitted

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

#ifdef TRIALDLL_EXPORT
#define TRIALDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TRIALDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

TRIALDLL_API MyMathFuncs* __stdcall new_MyMathFuncs(double offset);
TRIALDLL_API void __stdcall del_MyMathFuncs(MyMathFuncs *myMath);
TRIALDLL_API double __stdcall MyAdd(MyMathFuncs* myMath, double a, double b);
// some other similar stuff

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

And the triallDLL.cpp file:

```
// trialDLL.cpp
#include "trialDLL.h"

TRIALDLL_API MyMathFuncs* __stdcall new_MyMathFuncs(double offset)
{
    return new MyMathFuncs(offset);
}

TRIALDLL_API void __stdcall del_MyMathFuncs(MyMathFuncs *myMath)
{
    delete myMath;
}

TRIALDLL_API double __stdcall MyAdd(MyMathFuncs *myMath, double a, double b)
{
    return myMath->Add(a, b);
}
// ... some other definitions
```

With these two files in the project, I added a property sheet to the project through visual studio 2010 property manager and added `TRIALDLL_EXPORT` to user macros. After all these, the nice Intellisense gives me error for each function defined in the .cpp file and complains "error: a function declared 'dllimport' may not be defined". So it appears that Intellisense doesn't find `TRIALDLL_EXPORT` defined. I thought it might make a difference if I actually build the project, but the result suggests the same error: "error C2491: 'new_MyMathFuncs' : definition of dllimport function not allowed". Then it is clear that the macro `TRIALDLL_EXPORT` is still not defined in compiling time.

After failing to add macro through visual studio, I also tried putting code line: `#define TRIALDLL_EXPORT` in trialDLL.cpp but it didn't help either. I wonder what's the proper way to do this? How do I inform the compiler that the micro is defined so that `TRIALDLL_API` evaluates to `dllexport` rather than `dllimport`?

Also, if I can build the .dll successfully, is there any systematic way to test/verify the functionality of the .dll?

Thanks for any help in advance! (Although I know it's an issue here on stackoverflow to put appreciation in the question, I feel myself impolite not to do so. Forgive me for any inefficiency caused by these lines.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"User macros" in VS property sheets have nothing to do with preprocessor macros. Put `TRIALDLL_EXPORT` into the property sheet's section `C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`

"User macros," which can only be defined in property sheets, allow you to create your own "variables" usable in Visual Studio properties, similar to the built-in ones `$(TargetName)`, `$(SolutionDir)` etc.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! By the way, for my curiosity, what does "User macros" do then?

Comment: @springRoll They're "variables" for properties you can set in Visual Studio. Like the built-in ones `$(TargetName)`, `$(SolutionDir)` etc. Property sheets allow you to create your own.

Answer (score 2):

As said in this [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815647/you-receive-a-compiler-c2491-error-message-when-you-try-to-define-data), you cannot apply the `__declspec(dllimport)` keyword to implement a function. You should use it only in the declaration. For example:

```
    // function declaration
    void __declspec(dllimport) funcB();

    // function definition
    void funcB() {
        //funcB code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
#error Where is my macro?
```

in the `#else` block of the header. Then experiment with the project settings or the `#define` until you get it right. Did you perhaps only add the property sheet to one configuration? Did you put the `#define` at the very top of the file? Do you have any PCH stuff that causes it to ignore your settings? And so on.

Comment: Thanks! It works if the `#define` is put on the very top of the .cpp file. What I did was putting it after the `#include` in the .cpp file. Can I ask why does it make a difference?

Comment: Macros are defined from the point where they are `#define`d until the point where they are `#undef`ed (or the end of the translation unit). If you put the `#define` below the `#include`, the macro won't be defined in the area of your header.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, I didn't ask myself before I asked you. I figured it out myself when I had a rest minutes ago. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks okay, and must work if TRIALDLL_EXPORT is actually defined. You most probably messed up that somehow (like set it for a different configuration or for just one file) or did not rebuild.

If you're completely lost, ask for the preprocessor output, and look at that. As with define there can not be dllimport around at all, the error is also impossible.

EDIT: I just noticed you wrote _I also tried putting code line: #define TRIALDLL_EXPORT in_ **trialDLL.cpp**. I thought you put it at top of the header for trial. Try that first just to see that it works fine. Then you can remove it after you found the proper place.